# inverse Laplace with Matlab

Tags: matlab, math, symbolic-math

I have a problem with finding inverse laplace of function with Matlab. I obtained following transfer function :
[image]

I tried methods like

```
syms s t;
    num=[0 0 0 1.658e24 -1.163e14 6.076e15];
    den=[1 3.334e09 1.005e15 1.675e24 5.025e27 1.675e33];
    numsym=poly2sym(num);
    densym=poly2sym(den);
    transfer=numsym./densym;
    ilaplace(transfer,s,t)
```

but did not get an acceptable result. Meaning Matlab simply returns :
[image]

Also I tried to use partial fraction expansion and I wrote transfer function respect to poles and zeros but when I added all the pieces I did not get the original transfer function.

```
syms s t;
num=[0 0 0 1.658e24 -1.163e14 6.076e15];
den=[1 3.334e09 1.005e15 1.675e24 5.025e27 1.675e33];
numsym=poly2sym(num);
densym=poly2sym(den);
transfer=numsym./densym;
[z,p,r]=residue(num,den);
transfer1=(z(1)/(s-p(1)))+(z(2)/(s-p(2)))+(z(3)/(s-p(3)))+(z(4)/(s-p(4)))+(z(5)/(s-p(5)));
transfer1=vpa(simplifyFraction((transfer1),'Expand',true),2)
the
```

The transfer1 variable after simplification is order 4 in numerator while the original transfer function is order 2. I would be very thankful if anyone help me  to find the transfer function of following expression by any method?

Comment: First, statements like "but did not get any result" are not helpful to anyone. Edit your question to indicate what actually occurs. Second, you might want to pay attention to the variable that your `poly2sym` outputs are in terms of –it's not `s` because you haven't specified a second argument. You probably also shouldn't expect symbolic/analytic solutions when your denominator is a fifth order polynomial (except in special cases).

Comment: I edited my question but I defined s and t to be symbolic and that's not an issue. I just run the code without any error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things to consider:

1. By calling `poly2sym` without a second argument to define the desired variable, `x` is being used. So `poly2sym([1 1])` returns `x + 1`. Here you want a polynom with variable `s`, because in `ilaplace` you state `s` being the initial variable. Therefore use `poly2sym([1 1],s)` which will give you `s + 1` as result.
2. Your output with the correction of point (1) is very long and contains unresolved elements like `symsum` and `RootOf` which originate from the algorithm behind `ilaplace`. With the command `vpa` you can eliminate this and get a numerical result as far as possible.

The code would be something like this:

```
syms s t;
num=[0 0 0 1.658e24 -1.163e14 6.076e15];
den=[1 3.334e09 1.005e15 1.675e24 5.025e27 1.675e33];
numsym=poly2sym(num,s);             % here the s as second argument
densym=poly2sym(den,s);             % here the s as second argument
transfer=numsym./densym;

timeexp = ilaplace(transfer,s,t);
timenum = vpa(timeexp);             % get numerical answer
pretty(timenum)                     % show the answer in nicer form
```

Now we can verify the answer in case you think this might be just a bunch of numbers. Therefore a comparison with WolframAlpha is helpful. We need to convert the symbolic expression to a function handle to plot the results:

```
timefun = matlabFunction(timenum);
a = linspace(0,1e-4,10000);
plot(a,real(timefun(a)))
```

This gives the following result:
[image: Matlab plot]

Compared to [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28inverse%20laplace%20%281.658e24*s%5E2%20-%201.163e14*s%20%2B%206.076e15%29%20%2F%20%28s%5E5%20%2B%20s%5E4*3.334e09%20%2B%20s%5E3%20*%201.005e15%20%2B%20s%5E2*1.675e24%20%2B%20s*5.025e27%20%2B%201.675e33%29%29%20t%3D%200%20to%201e-4), we can say that our result is definitely plausible.

[image: WolframAlpha plot]

Answer (score -1):

I might be missing something but the inverse transfer function of a Polynomial Function is just the inverse of the ration of polynomials.

Namely, if you have $ F \left( S \right) = \frac{ {P}*{1} \left( s \right) }{ {P}*{2} \left( s \right) } $ the inverse is given by $ F \left( S \right) = \frac{ {P}*{2} \left( s \right) }{ {P}*{1} \left( s \right) } $.

What you need to deal with is the zeros of the polynomial at the numerator - This might explain the Delta functions.